# Is it possible to find a torrent in DHT network without knowing its hash?

Tags: bittorrent

I used trackerless bittorrent to send private files (but not so secret such as weekend photos) to my friends. It is convenient because it does not require any file-sharing services, can be used to transfer large files, allows to send directory without using archive files, uses swarm bandwidth and so on.

However, I have concern if someone can find these torrents using DHT. Is it really possible (without knowing hash)?

And how do search engines like [btdigg](http://btdigg.org/) enumerate DHT torrents? Is it possible to enumerate (nearly) all of torrents registered inside DHT network?

Comment: Even using DHT one peer has to have a torrent file for some information otherwise no one could find it, By searching for file names could give results, so always make your folder and file names generic goop of letters and numbers before distribution. "It is worth noting that BitTorrent can not ditch the .torrent format entirely and rely solely on Magnet links. The .torrent files hold crucial information that is needed to start the downloading process, and this information has to be available in the swarm." https://torrentfreak.com/bittorrents-future-dht-pex-and-magnet-links-explained-091120/

Comment: When creating a torrent, you should mark it "private", this flag will hint clients to disable DHT, PEX, LPD.

Comment: Then you have to send .torrent file — it's simpler than sending whole content but still extra step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, I have concern if someone can find these torrents using DHT. Is it really possible (without knowing hash)?

yes

> And how do search engines like btdigg enumerate DHT torrents? Is it possible to enumerate (nearly) all of torrents registered inside DHT network?

The DHT as originally specified is not enumerable per se, but an extension ([BEP 51](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0051.html)) aims to change that. But even without that each lookup for a torrent visits many nodes in the process, so it is possible for nodes to passively observe traffic and gather infohashes over time. It's not deterministic, but a large fraction of infohashes can be gathered that way.

For the moment your best approach should be to encrypt the files before torrenting them. E.g. 7zip [provides fairly strong encryption](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/29375).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, https://btdig.com/ is one DHT search engine.

It also allows searching for filenames within torrents.